# Call a kdb function passing another function as argument using sendSync method of qpython(kdb)

Tags: kdb

In the KDB server, we have two functions defined as

```
q)t:{0N!x[`min]; 0N!x[`max];}
q).up.map:{[keyList; valueList] keyList!valueList}
```

The KDB server, does not allow to pass dict`()!()` as an argument directly to a function, rather one has to use .up.map.
Calling `t` function from kdb would be like

```
q)t[.up.map[`min`max;10 20]]
```

I want to call the `t` function from qpython `sendSync()` method passing another function **.up.map[`min`max;10 20]** as an argument to `t`.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a solution in the qptyhon doc - https://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/qpython.html#qpython.qconnection.QConnection.sendSync

Error -
When I tried sendSync() method, below error is raised -
`qpython.qtype.QException: b'['`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a lambda for this. That way it's just the arguments that need be serialized:

```
q.sendSync("{t[.up.map[x;y]]}", qlist(["min", "max"], qtype=QSYMBOL_LIST), [10, 20])
```

If that's not permitted, you could create it as a named wrapper function on the kdb side, which could be.

Alternatively, you could format your call with arguments as a string. A bit hacky; but workable for simple input.

```
q.sendSync(f"t[.up.map[`{'`'.join(['min', 'max'])};{' '.join(['10', '20'])}]]")
```

Answer (score 3):

> The KDB server, does not allow to pass dict()!() as an argument directly to a function, rather one has to use .up.map.

May I know why this is so? It's not a bad idea to challenge the original design before looking for workarounds. If dictionary were allowed as its parameter, it could have been as simple as

```
params = QDictionary(qlist(numpy.array(["min", "max"], dtype=numpy.string_), qtype=QSYMBOL_LIST),
                     qlist(numpy.array([10, 20], dtype=numpy.int64), qtype=QLONG_LIST))

with qconnection.QConnection(host='localhost', port=5000) as q:
    q.sendSync("t", params)
```

If you want to do what you can do in q console via qpython, it's actually also simple: you pass the same string over. Effectively it's the same mechanism as a q client passing a string via IPC to the server, where the string is parsed and evaluated. Here you need to convert the input to the given string format in your Python code, thus not as clean as the above (although it looks more verbose).

```
with qconnection.QConnection(host='localhost', port=5000) as q:
    q.sendSync("t[.up.map[`min`max;10 20]]")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is insightful. Will rethink kdb design. Accepting other answer based on response time.